# HADOOP - get nodename inside mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapper, nodename

I'm writing a mapper and would like to know if it is possible to get the nodename, where the mapper is running.

Answer (score 3):

Hadoop automatically moves your MapReduce program to where your data is so I think you can just do getHostName() (if you're using Java that is) and it should return the name of the node on which your program is running.

```
java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

If you're using other languages such as Python, Ruby, etc. (i.e. using HadoopStreaming), the same idea holds true so you should be able to use the appropriate function/method available in those languages to get the host name.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration value `fs.default.name` will most probably give you a URL to the namenode, and if you get an instance of the FileSystem (`Filesystem.get(conf)`) you should be able to call the `getUri()` method to get the same information.